# Change header CSS upon scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying the achieve the same header fade in/fade out effect as this website:
http://www.shopstyle.com/

If you go to the website and scroll downwards, you'll see that the initial header is transparent but as you scroll down a certain number of pixels, the CSS switches to a solid background. Is this done via jquery/js or possible via CSS3?

Thank You

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not possible via CSS alone since CSS cannot select the scroll top.  It's very easy to do via javascript, though.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("#header").addClass("not-transparent");
    }
    else {
        $("#header").removeClass("not-transparent");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm assuming that '>100' means greater than 100 pixels right?

Comment: @user2028856 yes; you can change that value to whatever works best for you

Comment: Okay this works great, is it possible to add multiple classes?

Comment: @user2028856 of course; just separate the classes by a space with `.addClass`

Answer (score 2):

Use **[jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/)** plugin to trigger a class change on the `header` at a specific scroll position/offset.  There is even an extension of Waypoints specifically for this purpose (sticky elements) [**here**](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/). You can animate it either with CSS3 transitions/animations or jQuery UI class change animations.

From a site I made recently that has a sticky header which also animates similar to the site you linked, this is all the JS I used for that feature:

```
$('.header-wrap').waypoint('sticky', {
    stuckClass: 'stuck',
    offset: -1
});
```

`offset: -1` means the change is triggered once the top of the `.header-wrap` element hits `-1px` in relation to the window (so basically once the window is scrolled AT ALL - if you put `-200` it would not fire until the window had been scrolled 200px).

The class `stuck` change handles all of the transparency, animation, position etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is waypoint native to jquery or is it an external plugin that I need to import? Also, I understand class 'header-wrap' is the top header and class 'stuck' handles the transparency, but what does class 'sticky' do?

Comment: @user2028856 It's an external plugin - you would need to include both `jquery.waypoints.min.js` and `waypoints-sticky.min.js` (as the sticky header thing is actually a 'sub plugin' of waypoints, tho you can accomplish the same thing just using waypoints itself).

Comment: The 'sticky' argument just tells Waypoints to use the "sticky elements" functionality (see http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/ for examples).  The `stuck` class has `position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;` and so forth, as well as CSS3 transitions for various properties that are animated (opacity and height in my case).

Answer (score 0):

A combination of javascript and CSS3 should do the trick. In essence what you need to do is listen to the $(window).scroll Event and at a certain y-offset, add a class (e.g. fill) to your header:

```
.header { transition: all 1s; }
.header.fill { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.25); }
```